# UITableView first row is scrolled up when view shows up

Tags: ios, uitableview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I ran into this very strange bug and have no idea how to fix it after trying all that I know. So if you can help it would be immensely helpful!!!

I have a `UIViewController` that is hosting a `tableView` whose `dataSource` and `delegate` is the viewController itself. I am using it to present some navigation options, it is being presented with the iOS package `ECSlidingViewController`.

A screenshot of what it looks like is the following:

[image]

Notice that there are only 2 items in the tableView now. But there is actually another item (the first one) that's above these two. However, that one is automatically scrolled up when the view shows up, and if I try to scroll it down, the first item is indeed visible, but the tableView automatically bounces back when I release the scrolling gesture.

I have tried `setContentOffset` for the tableView, and `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` in `viewWillAppear` and none of them works.

The menu items are set as a property of the VC itself in villDidLoad, which looks like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Run Test", @"Test Log", @"About", nil];
    // setup the dataSource and delegate for tableView
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:ANCHOR_RIGHT_REVEAL_AMOUNT];
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;
}
```

As you can see the first item is `@"Run Test"`, which is scrolled off screen automatically for no reason. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Where are you setting the frame of the table view?

Comment: Yes. That looks like the tableView Frame top bounds lie further on top.

Comment: @Fogmeister it was drag and dropped in Xcode, but I'll try to set it again.